# Updated NDK to r9c from r8e and got error "No rule to make target"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have updated NDK to r9c from r8e and got error `No rule to make target`

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/bullet/src/LinearMath/btAlignedAllocator.
cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/main_soft//bullet/src/LinearMath/btAlign
edAllocator.o'.  Stop.
```

Previously my configure files were Ok and I just switched NDK version.

Android.mk line that adds that file. Files added before that line were Ok.

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/maincode.cpp 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/data/Friends.cpp 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(addprefix /bullet/src/LinearMath/, $(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/bullet/src/LinearMath/*.cpp)))
```

Comment: Please provide Android.mk file also. There is a bug in NDK 8 concerning how file paths are interpreted and probably that leads to some kind of a mismatch in NDK 9.

Comment: @user2359247 Thank You! You pointed me at the right direction. Files before were added one by one and bullet has some makemagic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other files start without slash. Try

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(addprefix bullet/src/LinearMath/, $(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/bullet/src/LinearMath/*.cpp)))
```